# What is best GAN model training cifar10 in current time?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network, dcgan

I want to know best GAN model for training cifar10.
I searched lots of models like DCGAN, WGAN, CGAN, SSGAN, SNGAN but it seems like I want better one.
Could you tell me what is best based on your experience or FID, IS score.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full leaderboard of GAN for CIFAR10([link](https://paperswithcode.com/sota/image-generation-on-cifar-10)). It is tested by Inception Score.

The current best method(or state of the art) is NCSN(paper :[link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.05600v2.pdf), code: [link](https://github.com/ermongroup/ncsn)).